# Delete multiple items in array

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net

I have a byte array

```
Dim b() as byte = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
```

I want delete without for next 3., 6., 9. items and so on

```
Dim Newb() as byte = {1,2,4,5,7,8}
```

How can i do?

Comment: Tag this with the appropriate language, might get more help

Answer (score 4):

Built-in .NET arrays do not allow deletions. You have several options open to you:

- Use `List(Of Byte())` collection.
- Make a new array of the correct size, and copy only the data that you need into it.
- Use LINQ API to filter the data from your array. The data would remain there, but the code that uses that data would not "see" it
- Use LINQ API to filter the data from your array, and call `ToArray` to make a new array from the results.